# libGDX shaperenderer code to link moving object

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to get a simple rectangle to move across the screen. I have defined my object and segregated the task of update and render. I know I have to put something in Gamerenderer, but don't know what code to use to reference my object. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

My object:

```
package com.mygdx.gameobjects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;

public class Egg {
    private Rectangle rect;

    public Egg(){
        rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        rect.x++;
        if (rect.x > 137) {
            rect.x = 0;
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getRect() {
        return rect;
    }
}
```

My Gameworld:

```
package com.mygdx.gameworld;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.mygdx.gameobjects.Egg;

public class GameWorld {

    Egg rect = new Egg();

    public void update(float delta) {
        Gdx.app.log("GameWorld", "update");
        rect.update(delta);
    }

    public Egg getRect() {
        return rect;
    }
}
```

GameRenderer

```
package com.mygdx.gameworld;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;

public class GameRenderer {

    private GameWorld myWorld;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    public GameRenderer(GameWorld world) {
        myWorld = world;
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true, 136, 204);
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    }

    public void render() {
        Gdx.app.log("GameRenderer", "render");
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(255 / 255.0f, 109 / 255.0f, 120 / 255.0f, 1);
        shapeRenderer.rect(xxxxxxxxxxxx); 
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }
}
```

What do I need to put between the brackets to see my rectangle i.e. xxxxxx should be replaced with what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

`Rectangle eggRect = myWorld.rect.getRect();`

on the line above. This gets a reference to your rectangle. Then replace your xxxxx with the relevant values:

`(eggRect.x, eggRect.y, eggRect.width, eggRect.height)`

The method is overloaded, do you can also add arguments for colour and so on if you want to

Comment: Actually you probably want `Rectangle eggRect = myWorld.getRect().getRect();` to stick to your OO principles, but you might want to rename that first `getRect()` as its name is a bit misleading, and it makes the code sound a bit silly

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out to answer my query. I can now see the rectangle move across the screen as I wanted.